# Custom "subdirectory" URLs by using MVC Routes in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on an MVC4 project, but I'm a little cloudy on how to achieve the following scenario with custom routing:

Say I have the following page structure

```
+ Home                (Desired URL: /Home)
+ Settings            (Desired URL: /Settings)
  - Emails            (Desired URL: /Settings/Emails)
  - SMS               (Desired URL: /Settings/SMS)
  - Notifications     (Desired URL: /Settings/Notifications)
```

Each page has it's own controller, model and view, as a few of the settings pages are quite complex. How would I achieve the desired URLs through Routing?

So far I've only been able to get **everything** to appear under `/Settings/{PageName}`, including the `Home` page, which obviously is no good.

I've looked online and searched but I can't find a clear example on how to achieve something like this when the pages all have different controllers.

How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have to use hard coded routes like this. is there a reason that you are using different controllers for each page?

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Home",
url: "Home",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
name: "Settings",
url: "Settings",
defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
name: "Emails",
url: "/Settings/Emails",
defaults: new { controller = "Emails", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: The controllers / settings configure a wide range of things and all use different tables - I'm doing it this way due to the whole "separation" idea that MVC introduced, however open for pointers if this wouldn't be best practice in this case..? I do understand how routing would be much easier if it were one controller.

Comment: in this situation you might want to look into using "Areas", it sounds like you need a "Settings" area. you will be able to group all your controllers, models, routes, views under the "settings" area. To create an area you can right click on your project > Add > Area...

Comment: In this case the "Area" looks like the best solution, thank you Matt.